# How to update this Bokeh ColumnDataSource?

Tags: python, pandas, bokeh

I have the following data frame:
[image]

I would like to populate a Bokeh `ColumnDataSource`

```
# Data Container
source = ColumnDataSource(dict(
    time=[],
    open=[],
    high=[],
    low=[],
    last=[],
    volume=[],
    numberoftrades=[],
    bidvolume=[],
    askvolume=[],
    candle_body_fill_color=[],
    candle_body_line_color=[],
    candle_wick_color=[]
))

# Create a new data-container.
new_data = dict(
    time=range_df.datetime,
    open=range_df.open,
    high=range_df.high,
    low=range_df.low,
    last=range_df.last,
    volume=range_df.volume,
    numberoftrades=range_df.numberoftrades,
    candle_body_fill_color=range_df.candle_color,
    candle_body_line_color=range_df.candle_color,
    candle_wick_color=range_df.candle_color
)

# Update the data container.
source.data = new_data
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-268-48250bd1dfa0> in <module>
     30 
     31 # Update the data container.
---> 32 source.data = new_data

(bunch of other stack info)

ValueError: expected an element of ColumnData(String, Seq(Any)), got {'time': 0     2021-02-12 20:01:00
1     2021-02-12 20:02:00
2     2021-02-12 20:03:00
3     2021-02-12 20:04:00
4     2021-02-12 20:05:00
              ...        
99    2021-02-12 21:55:00
100   2021-02-12 21:56:00
101   2021-02-12 21:57:00
102   2021-02-12 21:58:00
103   2021-02-12 21:59:00

(and it just goes on and on to list my data frame bits)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using this fixed the issue:

```
# Create a new data-container.
new_data = dict(
    time=range_df['datetime'],
    open=range_df['open'],
    high=range_df['high'],
    low=range_df['low'],
    last=range_df['last'],
    volume=range_df['volume'],
    numberoftrades=range_df['numberoftrades'],
    candle_body_fill_color=range_df['candle_color'],
    candle_body_line_color=range_df['candle_color'],
    candle_wick_color=range_df['candle_color'],
)
```

Not sure why we can't use the `.` notation anymore. I'm sure that used to work before.